# HTML not showing inside IF statement (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have the following problem. I am using Advanced Custom Fields for Wordpress to create a subtitle field for a post. I like to give this subtitle some styling but my HTML code within the IF-statement doesn't show on the page. The $subtitle does show.

```
<?php $subtitle = the_field('subtitle'); ?>
<?php if(strlen(trim($subtitle)) > 0): ?>
  <div class="post-sub-title"><?php $subtitle; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I spent hours searching for similar problems but couldn't find any solutions. So this must probably be a rookie mistake on my part.

**Solution**

```
<?php $subtitle = get_field('subtitle'); ?>
<?php if(strlen(trim($subtitle)) > 0): ?>
  <div class="post-sub-title"><?php $subtitle; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Changed the_field() to get_field(). Kuddo's to Aditya Vikas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this piece of code :

```
<?php if(strlen(trim($subtitle)) > 0): ?>
  <div class="post-sub-title"><?=$subtitle?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

instead of this :

```
<?php if(strlen(trim($subtitle)) > 0): ?>
  <div class="post-sub-title"><?php $subtitle; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and also one more thing !

`the_field()` is not a default WordPress function

the 'whatever' plugin you are using might have a corresponding function:

`get_field()`

Comment: I tried what you suggested. But it didn't work. The <div> still doesn't show. Only the variable $subtitle (wich contains some plain text) does.

Comment: Changing the the_field() to get_field() fixed to problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You should echo/print it (The subtitle variable).

```
<div class="post-sub-title"><?php echo $subtitle; ?></div>
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your response but this doesn't fix the problem for the HTML not being shown.

Comment: Then I guess the length of the data in subtitle is not greater than zero after trim function is called. Or you must have a bug somewhere else in your code, not the part you provided. **Edit:** Try print it without using the if statement and see if it can print.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
<?php $subtitle = get_field('subtitle'); ?>
<?php if(!empty(trim($subtitle))): ?>
  <div class="post-sub-title"><?php $subtitle; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks.